# Buttons In Embed (Discord.py)

Tags: button, discord, discord.py, embed

I have been trying to make a fake nitro command. I made an accept button under the embed that takes the user to a link (probably a troll GIF image or picture).

Currently, this is the code.

```python
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import *
from discord_buttons_plugin import *


  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    buttons = ButtonsClient(client)


  @commands.command(name='nitro')
  @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
  async def nitro(self,ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
      member = ctx.author



    embed = discord.Embed(title = "**You've been gifted a subscription!**",
                          description = f"||**{member.mention}**|| has gifted you Nitro for **1 month!**",
                          color = 0xc17ce0)

    embed.set_image(url = 'https://media.threatpost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/103/2021/04/19145523/Discord-Nitro-e1618858537976.png' )

    await buttons.send(
      content = None,
      embed = embed,
      channel = ctx.channel.id,
      components = [
        ActionRow([
          Button(
            style = ButtonType().Link,
            label = "Accept",
            url = "https://c.tenor.com/Bvb1iMhQQUUAAAAC/gorilla-middle-finger.gif"
          )
        ])
      ]
    )
```

It’s not showing any error, but the command is not working. How can I do it?

Comment: The code as posted is not valid Python code: "`def __init__(self, client):` ... `IndentationError: unexpected indent`"

Answer (score 0):

Those are third-party APIs which are similar to [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/). For using interactions and buttons in *discord.py*, you can use Discord's master version which can be downloaded by doing:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

Support regarding that will be available at their [Official Support server](https://discord.gg/r3sSKJJ).